# How to write sorting of strings with some additional rules

Tags: java, algorithm, selenium, automated-tests

I have a problem with the testing sort strings with an addition conditions.

Table contains a column which contains some string.
The strings can be sorted in alphabetical order. 
But there are additional conditions that the lines beginning with symbol "[" has lower priority than starting with a digit.

Firstly, I don't know algorithm.
Secondly, I don't know how to test, but in main way I should use algorithm which uses for sorting (but if algorithm contains incorrect implementation, so test is not find the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write a custom comparator](http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-sort-object-in-java-comparator-comparable-example.html) which implements all the conditional rules and check if if holds that

```
MyCustomComparator c = new MyCustomComparator();

for(int i=0; i < tab.size()-1; i++){
    if(!c.compare(tab[i], tab[i+1])){
        throw new Exception("Not sorted");
    }
}
```

Where `tab` is a collection of your sorted strings.

EDIT: This of course assumes that the conditional rules are not contradictory for example situations like `a < b && b < c && c < a` do not occur.

Answer (score 2):

The hard part has been done already: implement the comparison algorithm. To actually test it, just create some data set, in arbitrary order, containing strings starting with a `[` and strings starting with a digit, then invoke your sort algorithm, and check that the strings are in the expected order:

```
List<String> toSort = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"[123", "1234", "[234", "0123"});
Collections.sort(toSort, new YourComparator());
assertEquals(Arrays.asList("0123", "1234", "[123", "[234"), toSort);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know the algorithm.

Comment: So the problem is not with testing the sorting algorithm as you state in your question, but in writing it? Why don't you ask that then?